# NUnit: configuration settings cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, web-config

I've written an NUnit test project against an ASP.Net project. The code being tested cannot find the configuration values (in Web.config) when invoked from my test project. What is the right way to provide these configuration settings so my tests will run?

Comment: Are you testing the actual *.aspx.cs classes that inherit from `Page` or are you testing stand-alone classes that contain logic separate from the pages that use them?

Comment: No, I'm testing standalone classes that reference NHibernate assemblies, which expect to find configuration values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on NUnit's documentation about [Configuration Files](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.5.3) - it's pretty good explained how to handle your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app.config file for your test project.  Just put the configuration values you need in here.

Comment: This is true, but I consider it a clear violation of DRY -- Don't Repeat Yourself -- making the system more brittle.